# View application exceptions in Weblogic

Tags: exception, web-applications, logging, weblogic12c

I had deploy an application in tomact server and it was running just fine. But when I migrated it to Weblogic 12c it is having some problem. I need to see the application logs where I can monitor the application exception stacktraces. Where do I go to see them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are capturing the exceptions and logging them using, let's say, log4j, they will be wherever you configured in log4j.
Though, that does not seem to be your case. So, take a look into your WebLogic managed server log and output files. Here is how to find where they are:

Log on to your WebLogic administration console (typically http://[your endpoint]:7001/console). Go to `Servers/[Server name]/Logging/General` and take a look into the `Log file name` property. Usually, this path is relative to your server's root directory (in a typical installation it would be something like `/mnt/domains/[your domain]/servers/[server name]`.
If the property is blank, usually the logs are in `[server name]/logs`.

Also, do not forget to also look into the .out files lying in the same folder.